# ScrollView cancels DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, navigation-drawer

I've got a little app that uses both DrawerLayout and LinearLayout (with an include tag), where I am able to go from one tab to another and select the menu with no problem. When I add ScrollView to my LinearLayout (`content_main`), I am able to scroll, but I no longer can switch between the existing tabs, nor select the menu. It basically cancels my DrawerLayout. What is the way to fix it?

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                                 tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<!-- VIEW I WANT TO PUT SCROLLVIEW IN -->
<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:id="@+id/linear_id"
            tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">


            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/text_id"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try put your scrollview inside a linear layout

Comment: `DrawerLayout` should have only one main content `View`. As you have it now, the included `content_main` is completely covering the `CoordinatorLayout` and everything in it. When you add the `ScrollView` to it, it intercepts the touch events that were previously "going through" the `LinearLayout` by itself. I'm not sure what kind of design you're going for, but the `CoordinatorLayout` and the included layout should all be combined into one, somehow.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Tried it, same issue

Comment: @MikeM. I've put everything in the DrawerLayout and it worked! Have to restructure the layout pages (as it's a bit of a mess at the moment), but I got what I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MikeM. explained, ScrollView intercepts the main content of the DrawerLayout, thus cancelling all the touch events. I've put ScrollView with my TextView in the DrawerLayout and it worked